# Cycles Preview Render 3D View not using CUDA

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I just installed a new GTX960 graphics card into my old 2008 Mac Pro. Cycles Rendering using CUDA works fine and fast. But when in editing mode (3D Render View), Blender clearly uses CPU instead of GPU computing.

CPU usage is at 100% (1 core used) and preview rendering is slow. It makes no difference whether I select "GPU" or "CPU" in the render settings pane. Same speed for the samples. So clearly CPU only.

I cannot find any error messages either.

What could be wrong?